# I'm not sure how this function puts the thread to sleep

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm reading a book on Clojure, and in the example they want to put data into a channel. However, the author mentions that the core.async go block to randomly sleep, and it specifies that the random-add function is responsible for making the block sleep for a random number of time. I've tried looking on the Clojure Docs and I can't find any information of async/go sleeping. And what also confused me the most was when the author said this about the random-add function.

"This random amount of time will be a function called random-add. It uses
a rand-int function that picks a random integer between 0 and 100,000. Then it uses it in a function that will sum up a vector filled with the number 1 of a random length"

Which doesn't make sense to me, because `(repeat 1 (rand-int 100000))` will first return a list of 1 random number in the range specified, and then the list is conj'd to the vector, and then reduce + will actually return a list of 1 element.

````clj
(ns async-tea-party.core
   (:require [clojure.core.async :as async]))

(def google-tea-service-chan (async/chan 10))
(def yahoo-tea-service-chan (async/chan 10))

(defn random-add []
  (reduce + (conj [] (repeat 1 (rand-int 100000)))))

(defn request-google-tea-service []
  (async/go
  (random-add)
  (async/>! google-tea-service-chan
  "tea compliments of google")))

(defn request-yahoo-tea-service []
  (async/go
  (random-add)
  (async/>! yahoo-tea-service-chan
  "tea compliments of yahoo")))

(defn request-tea []
  (request-google-tea-service)
  (request-yahoo-tea-service)
  (async/go (let [[v] (async/alts!
    [google-tea-service-chan
    yahoo-tea-service-chan])]
    (println v))))```

No errors, just don't quite understand how this code makes any sense, especially with "async/go (random-add)" because (random-add) returns a list?
````

Comment: it looks like an error. that should probably be `(reduce + (repeat (rand-int 100000) 1))`. If it is really in the book, you probably should report about this mistake, for it to be fixed in next editions

Comment: @leetwinski Somehow the code works though

Comment: well it works, but it really doesn't sleep for random time, rather it is more or less constant, since reduce sums the list of one number. While the intended behavior is to sum the list consisting of random amount of digit `1`. So, syntactically it is correct, while semantically it is not

Comment: It's not a list of one number, though. It's a list of one element, and that element is itself a list of many numbers. Summing any one-element list returns the element unmodified, even if that element is not a number.

Comment: @amalloy `(reduce + (conj [] (repeat 1 (rand-int 100000))))` => `(87576)`, ok it is a list, but still the length is 1, since the order of args to `repeat` is wrong. Anyhow this implementation seems to be wrong, since `random-add` execution was intended to run for some random time

Comment: Oh ha, I didn't realize `repeat` has its arguments in the wrong order in addition to the list nesting being wrong.